# 415 Unsupported Media Type with form-data and python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to send a POST request to make a new record in the database and upload an image through postman but I get the following error

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>415 Unsupported Media Type</title>
<h1>Unsupported Media Type</h1>
<p>Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not &#39;application/json&#39;.</p> 
doing some research I found adding Content-Type: in the headers
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p1nv.png)
I am submitting the form like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF3ar.png)
I tried to add Content Type: multipart/form-data but got the same error
added the code used

product.py

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'upload')

def save_product():
    connection = get_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    createdAt = datetime.now() 

    data = request.get_json() 
    name = data.get("Name")
    description = data.get("Description")
    unitPrice = data.get("UnitPrice")
    salePrice = data.get("SalePrice")
    amount = data.get('Amount')
    active = data.get("Active", 1)
    categoryId = data.get("CategoryId")
    image_file = request.files.get("Image")

    errors = validation_product(data)

    if errors:
        return {'validation': errors}

    cursor.execute(duplicate_records(), (name,))
    search = cursor.fetchall()

    if search:
        return {"error": "El producto ya existe, intenta con otro nombre"}
    else:
        values = (name, 
            description, 
            unitPrice, 
            salePrice, 
            amount, 
            active, 
            categoryId, 
            createdAt, 
            createdAt)
        cursor.execute(insert_product(), values)
        productId = cursor.lastrowid

        if image_file:
            if validate_image(image_file):
                #Genera un nombre unico para la imagen
                filename = secure_filename(image_file.filename)
                extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
                new_filename = str(uuid.uuid4()) + extension
                save_path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, new_filename)
                

                image_file.save(save_path)

                send_image(productId, save_path)

                cursor = connection.commit()
    
        return {'message': 'Producto registrado correctamente'}
```

imageProduct.py

```
from database.db import get_connection

def send_image(productId, imageUrl):
    from models.querys.queryProduct import image
    
    connection = get_connection()
    cursor = connection.commit()
    values = (productId, imageUrl)
    cursor.execute(image(), values)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    return True
```

validateImage.py

```
from PIL import Image

def validate_image(file):
    try:
        img = Image.open(file)
        img.verify()
        return True
    except (IOError, SyntaxError):
        return False
```

app.py

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def sendProdouct():
    product = save_product()

    response = {
        key: value for key, 
        value in product.items()
        if key in ['validation', 'error', 'message']}

    return jsonify(response)
```

I would really appreciate your support